AWK function for enclosing an arbitrary regex in parentheses
I would like to encapsulate a user-provided ERE in parenthesis while retaining its original meaning when I use it with awk's match, split, sub, etc... If you wonder why I want to do that then you can check here.
Here's a dumb implementation of ere_parenthesize:
awk '
    function ere_parenthesize(ere) {
        return "(" ere ")"
    }
    { print $1, "->", ere_parenthesize($1) }
'

Which I initially wrote without thinking about the possibility of having a closing parenthesis in the ERE. It turns out that there's a lot of things to consider for doing that seemingly simple task.
Sample input:
)
\)
[)]
[])]
[^])]
[\])] # the result differs for POSIX and non-POSIX
\()
[(])
\(\)
\([)]
(\))
([)])
(a|b)
((a)|(b))
[[:punct:])]
[[=abc=])]
[[.c.])]
[[=]=])]

Expected output:
)             ->  (\))
\)            ->  (\))
[)]           ->  ([)])
[])]          ->  ([])])
[^])]         ->  ([^])])
[\])]         ->  ([\]\)])        #  POSIX
[\])]         ->  ([\])])         #  non-POSIX
\()           ->  (\(\))
[(])          ->  ([(]\))
\(\)          ->  (\(\))
\([)]         ->  (\([)])
(\))          ->  ((\)))
([)])         ->  ([)])
(a|b)         ->  ((a|b))
((a)|(b))     ->  (((a)|(b)))
[[:punct:])]  ->  ([[:punct:])])
[[=abc=])]    ->  ([[=abc=])])
[[.c.])]      ->  ([[.c.])])
[[=]=])]      ->  ([[=]=])])

How would you write ere_parenthesize?

ASIDE
I thought of a way of checking if a regex engine is POSIX-compliant (see explanation in an "answer" below):
edit: now using ^ in the regex, as it makes more sense.
is_posix_ere_engine = match("\\", /[\^]/)


may i ask what purpose does ((Y)) serve, other than an extra layer of superfluous (…) ? If the user's intent were to make Y into a capturing group (e.g. for 4-argument variant of split()), then the extra layer doesn't seem to provide additional benefit to the user

The problem is about putting parenthesis around a regex. If I give you a string in $1 and a regex in $2, then what do you need to do for split($1,a,"("$2")") to yield exactly the same result as split($1,a,$2)

I haven't investigated further, but what about a routine to check for balanced parenthesis (braces and brackets) if that is one of the points causing problems? A simple iteration over the string (ere) using a var like paren and for each '(' do paren = parent + 1 and for each ')' do paren = paren - 1. After the iteration if (paren != 0) then the groupings are unbalanced? I say I haven't investigated further as that was just an observation regarding the ere(s) that you give that easily fail. Seems like you will need to do it in steps to eliminate what you don't want?

@DavidC.Rankin Yes, that's what I'm trying to implement, but counting the ( and ) correctly is really hard when they appear within [ ].

This does not seem to match any ( or ) between [ or ]:   https://regex101.com/r/jg0hgj/1

@Luuk it does, if you add other characters before the ]

@Fravadona : using your example [[:punct:])] -> ([[:punct:])]) — the left side version already fully captures what the user want, so the extra pair of (….) on the outside literally does nothing except potentially increasing the DFA's complexity (assuming it wasn't optimized away). Another point - since your function is already rewriting the regex anyway, [[:punct:]] already includes that right ), so adding the extra one there doesn't capture anything extra

@Fravadona : the whole point of bracket expressions is that things described inside could be treated atomically against the string being matched, so for these 2, [)] -> ([)]) and [])] -> ([])]), the left side versions are already perfectly valid ERE. Making them into the right side versions doesn't alter the outcome of split(…) one single bit. The right side ones are still valid ERE, but with an extra pair of superfluous parens that do nothing.

@RAREKpopManifesto You're right, there's no much point in adding parentheses around  expressions that don't contain alternations | nor anchors ^ $, but detecting the cases where the parentheses are not needed would require a lot more code... You're also right with [[:punct:])] which doesn't make any sense; it's just an example of what the function needs to support.

@RAREKpopManifesto Well, the main point of making an ERE self-contained (inside parentheses) is that it allows its concatenation with an other self-contained ERE.

@Fravadona : [(] is a fully self-contained ERE that you can directly concat with others, as well as apply [(]* [(]+ [(]{4,7} etc.

@Fravadona : my point was simply - the function should be able to detect EREs that are already properly self-contained and thus can avoid an extra pair of superfluous (…) that adds nothing (unless you need to be capturing that particular ERE subset, in which case, ( … ) are unavoidable. ([ …. ] are self-contained without being part of any capture or use as backreferences (in other flavors of regex) - personally i still prefer ([(]) over (\() (if you need the capture), as it gets really messy as to which ( ) applies to what, where as having them "caged" [(] is cleaner)

@Fravadona : or for instance (\)) —> ((\))) the left hand side variant already has everything you need, so the right hand side is just more verbose without providing any additional utility (and makes it more confusing if you need to be counting capturing group #s). That's on top of the fact that ((\))) ends up getting the same thing captured TWICE, once as ( (\)) ), and once more as (( \) ))

@RAREKpopManifesto Indeed, but it's difficult to determine when a regex is already self-contained. Even if it's a waste, the simplest way to make sure that the resulting ERE is self-contained is to add parentheses around it.

Not an answer, just an explanation for the OPs POSIX-compliance check code at the end of the question that was getting far too long to be a comment or part of an "aside" in the question:
Per POSIX a backslash in a bracket expression is literal but some awks such as GNU awk interpret backslashes in a bracket expression as escape characters so that characters that are otherwise metachars in a bracket expression, i.e. ^, -, and ], can appear in other locations than where POSIX dictates they need to appear to be considered literal.
Per POSIX, to be considered literal ^ must not be at the start, ] must be at the start, and - must be at the start or end of a bracket expression.
In GNU awk and some others that is also the case but additionally you can put a \ in front of them and then put them anywhere inside the bracket expression. A consequence of that is that a backslash on it's own in a bracket expression is always treated as an attempt to escape the character that follows it so:

If you want a literal \ inside a bracket expression you need to double it to escape it, [\\]
If inside a bracket expression you put a \ in front of a character that is not one of the above listed bracket expression metachars (^, -, or ]), and is not part of a known/documented escape sequence such as \t for tab, e.g. /[\y]/, then it's now treated the same way as trying to escape an ordinary character anywhere else in the regexp, i.e. is undefined behavior and your awk can do whatever it likes with that (GNU awk will treat the char after it, y in that example, as literal, and if you ran it as gawk --posix it would also print a warning like awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence \y' is not a known regexp operator`).

So in the OPs POSIX-checking code in the "aside" towards the bottom of their question, if /[\(]/ matches a backslash in a string then the \ in [\(] is being treated as a literal backslash, not escaping (, and so is behaving in the POSIX-defined way, not the way gawk and some others would behave.
Here's a table of POSIX vs gawk (and some others) differences regarding how to get these characters to be treated as literal in a bracket expression (all can have a ^ at the start for negation, x and y just represent any or no other characters):



Literal
POSIX
gawk and some others




\
[x\y]
[x\y] or [x\\y]


^
[x^y]
[x^y] or [\^xy]


-
[-xy] or [xy-]
[-xy] or [xy-] or [x\-y]


]
[]xy]
[]xy] or [x\]y]



* eg Here's an example of GNU awk handling backslashes before a literal char vs before a metachar in non-POSIX and POSIX modes:
Non-POSIX mode:
$ echo 'a\b' | awk '/[x\y]/'              # literal char
a\b
$ echo 'a\b' | awk '/[x\\y]/'             # literal char
a\b
$ echo 'a\b' | awk '/[x\^]/'              # meta-char
$ echo 'a\b' | awk '/[x\\^]/'             # meta-char
a\b

POSIX mode:
$ echo 'a\b' | awk --posix '/[x\y]/'      # literal char
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\y' is not a known regexp operator
$ echo 'a\b' | awk --posix '/[x\\y]/'     # literal char
a\b
$ echo 'a\b' | awk --posix '/[x\^]/'      # meta-char
$ echo 'a\b' | awk --posix '/[x\\^]/'     # meta-char
a\b

Note the warning output by gawk for echo 'a\b' | awk --posix '/[x\y]/' claims that \y is not a known regexp operator but POSIX says:

The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped
 ( \ ) is undefined, except in the context of a bracket
expression

and y is an ordinary character so within a bracket expression \y IS defined to be a literal backslash followed by the letter y.
The gawk manual says the following about how it treats \s within bracket expressions:

To include one of the characters \, ], -, or ^ in a bracket
expression, put a \ in front of it. For example:
[d\]] matches either d or ]...
The treatment of \ in bracket expressions is compatible with other
awk implementations and is also mandated by POSIX.

IMO it'd be more correct to say "and is also mandated by POSIX in all other regards" or similar since the behavior described in their first sentence regarding escapes before the 4 mentioned metachars is clearly not the behavior mandated by POSIX.
References:

POSIX awk spec, regular expressions
section
POSIX regular expressions spec, BRE+ERE bracket expressions section
POSIX regular expressions spec, extended regular expressions
section
GNU awk manual, regular expressions
section


It's interesting to see that in this matter even GNU's awk --posix doesn't behave like POSIX specifies. On Solaris echo -E 'a\b' | command -p awk '/[x\y]/' outputs a\b

@Fravadona Right, though last time I had access to a SOlaris box about 15 years ago I don't think at that time there were any truly POSIX compliant awks on Solaris. Even the /usr/xpg4/bin awk had some variation (e.g. either didn't support character classes or don't support intervals like {2,5}, I don't recall but I THINK nawk supported one but not the other and xpg4 awk was the opposite).

++ for POSIX compliance details.

One of the best "Not an answer" Answers I've had the pleasure of reading. So this seems to be an instance were there is an AAFU (adapted from the legal CAFU [Case All Fouled Up]), except here we have AwkAFU.  (substitute your favorite 'f' word in the acronym) The separation of behaviors is very helpful.

Here comes a possible implementation of ere_parenthesize. The code tries to accurately determine whether a character is part of a bracket expression while parsing the input ERE character by character; because only the unpaired and unescaped ) that are not part of a bracket expression shall be backslash-escaped.
I made a few choices:

Unclosed bracket expressions and unpaired parentheses will trigger a fatal error.

I append an additional \ in the EREs that end with a single \ that is not part of a bracket expression (well, \ being the last char of a bracket expression means that the bracket expression is unterminated => fatal error). Some awks accept that last \ in an ERE, others trigger a fatal error; the function here always allows (and fixes) it.

The classes [:, [= and [. in bracket expressions are forced to end with :], =] and .] respectively. Further testing on multiple awk implementations might be necessary before validating this behaviour.


note: The function differentiates between POSIX & non-POSIX regex engines and adapts the output accordingly.
function ere_parenthesize(ere    ,out,i,j,n,c,is_posix_engine,in_parentheses,in_bracket_context) {

    is_posix_engine = match("\\",/[\^]/)

    out = ""
    n = length(ere)
    in_parentheses = 0
    in_bracket_context = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        c = substr(ere,i,1)

        if (in_bracket_context)
        {
            if (in_bracket_context == 1) # first char of the bracket expression
            {
                if (c == "^") {
                    out = out c
                    c = substr(ere,++i,1)
                }
                if (c == "]") {
                    out = out c
                    c = substr(ere,++i,1)
                }
                ++in_bracket_context
            }
            if (c == "[")
            {
                out = out c
                c = substr(ere,++i,1)
                if ( c == ":" || c == "=" || c == "." )
                {
                    # There are some discrepancies between awk implementations
                    # regarding how "[:", "[=", and "[." can terminate. For
                    # example /[[=ab]/ is invalid with GNU but valid with BSD.
                    # As it have an effect on the closing of the whole bracket
                    # expression, I chose to enforce a POSIX behavior here.
                    # Warning! May god bless you.

                    j = index(substr(ere,i+1), c"]")
                    if (!j)
                    {
                        print "ere_parenthesize: unmatched ["c" in /"ere"/" | "cat 1>&2"
                        exit 1
                    }
                    out = out substr(ere,i,j+2)
                    i += j+1
                    continue
                }
            }
            else if (c == "]")
            {
                in_bracket_context = 0
            }
            else if (c == "\\" && !is_posix_engine)
            {
                out = out c
                c = substr(ere,++i,1)
            }
            out = out c
        }
        else # not in_bracket_context
        {
            if (c == "[")
            {
                in_bracket_context = 1
            }
            else if (c == "\\")
            {
                # If a \ is left alone at the end of the ERE we will duplicate it
                out = out c
                if (i < n)
                    c = substr(ere,++i,1)
            }
            else if (c == "(")
            {
                ++in_parentheses
            }
            else if (c == ")")
            {
                if (in_parentheses)
                    --in_parentheses
                else
                    out = out "\\"
            }
            out = out c
        }
    }
    if (in_parentheses || in_bracket_context)
    {
        print "ere_parenthesize: unmatched ( or [ in /"ere"/" | "cat 1>&2"
        exit 1
    }
    return "(" out ")"
}

Output from Solaris's XPG4 awk (POSIX):
)             ->  (\))
\)            ->  (\))
[)]           ->  ([)])
[])]          ->  ([])])
[^])]         ->  ([^])])
[\])]         ->  ([\]\)])
\()           ->  (\(\))
[(])          ->  ([(]\))
\(\)          ->  (\(\))
\([)]         ->  (\([)])
(\))          ->  ((\)))
([)])         ->  (([)]))
(a|b)         ->  ((a|b))
((a)|(b))     ->  (((a)|(b)))
[[:punct:])]  ->  ([[:punct:])])
[[=abc=])]    ->  ([[=abc=])])
[[.c.])]      ->  ([[.c.])])
[[=]=])]      ->  ([[=]=])])


AL: You're welcome to test random regexps in multiple awks

++ for a very good solution. When I understood the question completely this  was the approach came to my mind also to read input char by char and escape only )s that are outside [...] and don't have a  \ before them.

Looks good to me so far, nice job.

You might want to change the error message print "awk: fatal... so it doesn't look like an error from awk (and send people scurrying off to the man pages!) but instead from your function.

@EdMorton A fatal error triggered by ere_parenthesize should mean that there's a problem with the ERE, so awk's documentation ought to be the right place to go; but sure, I changed it.

@Fravadona I understand where you're coming from but that leading string awk: should tell a user which tool is reporting the error and a user should be able to grep the documentation or source code for the tool to find exactly that message. Maybe the thing to do is try to use the regexp and let awk be the one to fail and report whatever error message that awk version reports? If I add match("",ere) to the top of your function and call it with echo '(a' | awk -f ere.awk it fails with awk: ere.awk:5: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched ( or \(: /(a/ which IS from awk.

@EdMorton That's nice idea, and that should take care of all malformed regexps. I can only see a single uncovered case, which is that /[[=ab]/ is valid in macOS's awk but illegal in ere_parenthesize

That way you're letting awk test the regexp and produce whatever error message the version of awk your function is being called from reports and so your code doesn't need to handle all possible invalid EREs it might be called with as it'll only ever see valid EREs. You're also getting a bit of free information that you can't get at in your code - the name of the file your script is stored in and line number where the error is detected which could be very useful to someone using it.

Hmm, that's interesting - [[=ab] is the start of a (bad) collation character, right? So collation chars are one more thing a POSIX awk should support but I could easily see BSD awk (mac) not doing so and then that would be a valid regexp to that awk.

@EdMorton It is; [[=a] fails in all awks that I tested, but the failure of [[=ab] is fifty/fifty

Right, that makes sense as [[=a is ALWAYS missing a terminating ] as that first [ is the start iof a brackt expression no matter what but [[=ab] is only invalid if you support collation characters since [= is the start-of-collation string inside a bracket expression that supports them (just like [: is the start of a character class), otherwise [[=ab] is just a character list of [, =, a, b inside a bracket expression.

I corrected my comment

Which reminds me - there are awks out there that don't support character classes and so would be happy with [[:space] in a regexp while a truly POSIX awk should fail with an unmatched ] error. Character classes in scripts are far more common than collation characters.

In the code I enforce the [: [= [. to be correctly terminated

I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're telling me in that last comment.

@EdMorton [[=ab] works with apple's awk and seems to be understood as an "equivalence" class, as it doesn't match a single =. On the other hand, [[=a] always crashes

Hmm, that sounds like a bug in BSD awk to me, it shouldn't be treating [[=ab] as an equivalence class without the =].

@EdMorton I ended up writing a POSIX gnusplit using ere_parenthesize; just to say that as long as ere_parenthesize is fully validated then it permits to do a lot of things in awk, even considering GNU awk

I understand what you're trying to do with j = index(substr(ere,i+1), c"]") but I wonder if you need to restrict that search to the part of the ERE before the next unescaped ], something like if ( match(substr(ere,i+1), /[^\\]\]/) && substr(substr(ere,i+1),RSTART,1) == c) so you don't trip over a malformed ere like [[=ab][=xy=]] which I THINK your current test would accept since there IS a =] in it, it's just not where it actually needs to be for it to be a valid POSIX regexp.

I tested and your current code would indeed reject '[[=ab]]' as invalid but would accept '[[=ab][=xy=]]' as valid. Ah, but you can't just match [^\\]]/ as that \ might have a second one before it and so it's actually NOT escaping the ]. Quite a tangle!

That got me wondering what your code would do with [[=ab\=]] and it accepted it so you do need a match("",ere) or similar at the top to help reject bad EREs (awk: ere.awk:5: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Invalid collation character: /[[=ab\=]]/) or your code will get even more complicated.
